# Activity workbooks to teach my child long vowel sounds?

Tags: teaching, reading, learning, books

I'm currently teaching my 4 year-old son how to read. I got him [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1939754526) phenomenal book, and he's doing really well learning short vowel sounds. It's very methodical and systematic and is constructed in a very logical way, my child is really absorbing a lot. Unfortunately, this book only teaches short vowel sounds but not long vowel sounds. I started searching for long vowel activity books online, I was sure I'll be able to find one quickly, but much to my dismay I couldn't find a single book on the subject! You would think that this is such a basic thing that every child needs to learn and that there would be many book options out there, but I couldn't find a single one! There are activity sheets that I can print out from reading mama and other sites for specific vowel patterns, but I find that they aren't as effective. For my child to be able to master the subject he needs an activity book with lots of lessons and practice to review them every day until he masters them.

I can buy these bundles of sheets and courses offered by some teachers online, but they are typically a fortune, and I cannot afford those. There are also a lot of reading activity books for long vowel sounds (like the BOB books) but my son is not up to that stage yet, he needs to be taught the rules of silent "e", "ee" "ai" "oo" etc., before he can move on to tackle reading exercises. So I'm looking for an affordable activity book that would teach him long vowels systematically and in a fun way. Any recommendations would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please see [What topics can I ask about here?](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic): shopping recommendations are explicitly off topic.

Answer (score 2):

Great job getting the foundation set up to prepare your son for reading! While I was doing some searching online, I too saw a ton of expensive workbooks meant for teachers however, there is a really good line of workbooks on [amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1402750579) by the "I am going to read" series. I recommend checking those out to start.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you Stephanie. They're really cheap and I'm going to get one. I'm just not sure if it's too advanced for my child, or not. I wish they would show preview. +1.

Comment: Hey! These are more just reading materials rather than activity books, but since they are tailored to 4-6 year olds they might workout. Getting one won't hurt, you can always save it for the next few months :) since your son will likely be a pro by then! https://www.amazon.com/gp/bookseries/B07D1DHDSH/ref=dp_st_0606338810

Comment: true, but I tend to be cautious and do it more slowly. I don't want to confuse him with words that are too much for him to handle and then he may regress. I want to do this right. this one actually looks pretty decent https://www.amazon.com/Im-Going-Read%C2%AE-Workbook-Vowels/dp/1402750579#customerReviews

Comment: This one also looks interesting https://www.amazon.com/Long-Vowels-Grades-1-2-Phonics/dp/0743933362/ref=pd_sbs_14_3/137-0729990-9943807?_encoding=UTF8&pd_rd_i=0743933362&pd_rd_r=8a7dec15-ad99-46dc-8df3-a8f530961acc&pd_rd_w=nrvQZ&pd_rd_wg=NTs1H&pf_rd_p=d28ef93e-22cf-4527-b60a-90c984b5663d&pf_rd_r=Z53QP5RWETE4Q1TV18CG&psc=1&refRID=Z53QP5RWETE4Q1TV18CG#customerReviews

Comment: The second link you gave might be a bit advanced since it says grades 1-2

Comment: and of course! best of luck to the both of you!

Comment: Right, I just noticed that. It's way too advanced!